# Generate unique statements using for loop on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which is grouped and aggregated

```
df_subsegment:
    segment         Sales   Income  Rent
0   A               184.37  224.24  5242.9  
1   B               45.42   176.79  6693.0  
<+100 rows>
```

I have created a list from the above dataframe:

```
    SubSegment_list = df_subsegment['segment'].unique()
    SubSegment_list

[out] array(['A', 'B'], dtype=object)


for i in SubSegment_list:
    var1 = df['Sales']
    var2 = df['Income']
    var3 = df['Rent']
    flag1 = 'up' if var1>0 else 'down'
    flag2 = 'up' if var2>0 else 'down'
    flag3 = 'leverage' if var3>0 else 'deleverage'
    print(f"{SubSegment_list[0]} Sales {flag1} {round(var1)} % vs LY while Total income {flag2} {var2}% vs LY creating {flag3}")
```

Lets consider that right now the list mentioned above has 2 values only, A and B. then the output gerenated out of this for loop contains two statements but both of them has same values as follows:

```
A Sales up 184 % vs LY while Total income up 224.24% vs LY creating leverage
A Sales up 184 % vs LY while Total income up 224.24% vs LY creating leverage
```

How can i generate two unique statements considering the data of each row as follows:

Expected output:

```
A Sales up 184% vs LY while Total income up 224.24% vs LY creating leverage
B Sales up 45% vs LY while Total income up 176.79% vs LY creating leverage
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

```
for _, value in df.iterrows():

    var1 = value['Sales']
    var2 = value['Income']

    seg1 = value['segment']

    flag1 = 'up' if var1>0 else 'down'
    flag2 = 'up' if var2>0 else 'down'

    print(f"{seg1} Sales {flag1} {var1}% vs LY while Total income {flag2} {var2}% vs LY creating leverage")

A Sales up 184.37% vs LY while Total income up 224.24% vs LY creating leverage
B Sales up 45.42% vs LY while Total income up 176.79% vs LY creating leverage
```

Comment: Could you explain the syntax or logic for the ```for``` statement please?

Comment: `iterrows` functions returns `index, row` information, check the documentation, I replaced indexed with `_` since we dont need to use it